# Contact form 7 file input button design

Tags: html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have installed Contact form 7 on my WordPress site, and have styled the rest of the fields successfully, but unfortunately I can't find a solution how to style the File Attach button. I have inserted the code that I have written in contact form 7 module in admin panel. Besides that, I have the CSS for it in style.css;

Can anyone help me?

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
<p>Your Name (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<p>Your Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
<p>Subject<br />
    [text your-subject] </p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-8">
<p>Your Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

[file* uploadcv limit:50000000 class:cv-upload]

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 ">
[recaptcha id:recapcha class:recapcha]
</div>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: input type field only change by using jquery

Comment: Can you link me to a live version of your contact page? I have a CSS hack I always use to style my file input buttons. I need to inspect the `elements` to adjust accordingly. :)

Comment: And @Deepaksaini, that's shameful to depend on jQuery for every portion of your project/page. You don't even need JavaScript. You can achieve this through pure CSS.

Comment: have a look on  my answer.

Comment: @AdamAzad unfortunetlyI cant give you the exact link beacuse the site is on my local machine. can you post the code, maybe i can try and figure it out :)

Comment: @elodpal, I already posted my answer. Just make the changes according to Contact Form HTML output for file input :)

Comment: @elodpal my code is working here is the example: http://www.hestawork.com/quiz/index.php/contact/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **HTml** like this

```
<div id="upload-file">
   <input type="file" name="photo" />
</div>
```

and **css**

```
#upload-file {
   background: url(images/custom-file-input.png) no-repeat;
}

#upload-file input {
    opacity: 0;
    display:inherit;
}
```

I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of using a recognized button for file input (since the framework is Bootstrap), so I use `.btn-file`

```css
    .btn-file {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .btn-file input[type=file] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        font-size: 100px;
        text-align: right;
        filter: alpha(opacity=0);
        opacity: 0;
        outline: none;
        background: white;
        cursor: inherit;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<span class="btn btn-success btn-file">
                        Browse <input name="file" type="file">
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i use

in contact form

> *Name
>       [text* your-name]
>
> *Email
>       [email* your-email]
>
> Subject
>       [text your-subject]
>
> input[type=submit]
>          {
>       background-color: #3498db;
>       color: #fff;
>       border: none;
>       padding: 7px 27px;    } textarea {height:100px;}
>
> Your Message
>       [textarea your-message]
>
> [submit "Send"]